# Facebook App Redirect Top Level Frame

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

Is it possible to redirect the top level page from within the iframe of a facebook app?

I'm building a facebook application that will appear in a tab with the JS SDK. I've added a normal a tag that links to the facebook page of the company who's responsible for the app (https://www.facebook.com/) but when I click this link i get:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/Somersby?ref=ts&fref=ts' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

It seems Facebook is blocking links in my application that redirect outside of the app's domain. Is there a way to redirect to the company page? Is there an API available to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood what was happening here. I forgot to add target="_top" to the link, so it was trying to change the source of the iframe, not the top level frame. It seems facebook can't be displayed in an iFrame, which was the source of the error message.